# Laravel - NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php - all pages except / route show error

Tags: php, laravel

The error that I am facing seems to be a common one. But the solutions I found on the various posts online, did not seem to solve my issue.

I am new to Laravel and have installed it on my local (WAMP) using a [tutorial link](https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-hello-world).

The initial set-up seemed to work fine and my route (http://localhost/laravel/larashop/public/) page worked. However any other routes that I add to the routes.php or web.php file do not seem to work. I get an error saying **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line xyz**.

My web.php file:

```
<?php

//works
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//does not work
Route::get('/hello',function(){
    return "welcome";
});

//does not work
//Route::get('hello', 'Hello@index');

//does not work
/*Route::get('hello',function(){
    return view('welcome');
});*/
```

I had used the *php artisan make:controller Hello* command to create the controller and added a simple index() function to it. But the links do not work even when I do not use the controller or the view (i.e. the `return "welcome"` function).

I get the following to response to the *php artisan route:list* command:

```
c:\wamp64\www\Laravel\larashop>php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | hello    |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
```

Any helps would be appreciated. I am stuck!

Comment: try this http://localhost/laravel/larashop/public/index.php/hello

Comment: why not use `php artisan serve` for it ?

Comment: Thanks! http://localhost/laravel/larashop/public/index.php/hello worked! So should I try using links in my code with index.php, like for form submissions etc? Or do I need to make some setting changes so that I do not need the index.php? ... As I mentioned, the link http://localhost/laravel/larashop/public/ works, but adding anything further is working only with index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you setup the web server is not exactly correct. The web server should be pointing to `public` folder. Then, you can just access it without the `public` URI.

Using the information you provided, if you point it to the public folder, you can access these without the `public` URL:

```
Route::get('/',function() { return 'Something'; })

http://localhost/laravel/larashop/


Route::get('/hello',function() { return 'Something'; })

http://localhost/laravel/larashop/hello
```

If you insist to point the web server to the root project folder which will include the public URI in the route(which highly not recommended), you can access your route as follows:

```
Route::get('/',function() { return 'Something'; })

http://localhost/laravel/larashop/public/


Route::get('/hello',function() { return 'Something'; })

http://localhost/laravel/larashop/public/hello
```

Comment: This was a test project that I was writing to learn Laravel. I would surely point the web server to the public folder once I am coding the actual project code. However, I hope that this should not cause the error?

Comment: @user7983103If you are just testing, you can actually run php artisan serve as a quick web server

Comment: If you think this is the answer, feel free to vote up and accept this as an answer :) @user7983103

Comment: php artisan serve solves the problem for my local. That should narrow down the issue to my setting up the server. So how should I be sure that I wont face the same issue when I run the code for production? I cant be using php artisan serve there?

Comment: If you point your web server to public directory, it will works exacly as how php artisan serve

Comment: ok! thanks a lot! then i guess I should have found the answer. would use php artisan serve for development and testing, and would point web server directly to the public directory on production.

Comment: @user7983103 Great! Please accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `php artisan serve`, as suggested by Demonyowh and geckob, solves my problem! Thank you!